# How to make single UIView in shape rectangle and square are embedded

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uibezierpath

How to make Single UIView in following shape?
A square embedded with rectangular shape. So i can scan barcode and QR code scan with in the same.

Please find the below picture for example!
[image]

Comment: try with iCarousel

Comment: Its a barcode and QR code scanner.

Comment: oh sorry, make the question as clear

Comment: You can use subviews to achieve it. So, whats new in that.